# Null Pointer Exception when Getting EditText Value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get EditText value through below code. The activity is used for adding two strings. In the layout, I already put onSave and onCancel method. But when I press button linked to onSave, it shows null pointer exception error.

Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddTimeActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.time_item);
}

public void onCancel(View view){
    this.setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
}

public void onSave(View view){
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    EditText timeView = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    String time = timeView.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(TimeTrackerActivity.TIME_KEY, time);

    EditText notesView = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.notes_view);
    String notes = notesView.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(TimeTrackerActivity.NOTES_KEY, notes);

    this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();

}
}
```

Layout:

```
...
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/notes_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
...
<Button
        android:onClick="onSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

<Button
        android:onClick="onCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel" />
...
```

Error Message from Debugger

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1123): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1123): at com.timetracker.AddTimeActivity.onSave(AddTimeActivity.java:34)
```

I tried to check and the value of timeView through debugger and it is null.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the id `time_view` (findViewById(R.id.time_view)), but you declare in the XML the ID `timeView` (`android:id="@+id/timeView"`). Make them the same and it should fix it.

Also, you should not call it on the view, but on the activity, e.g:

```
EditText timeView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How come I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 2):

Your xml has

```
 android:id="@+id/timeView"
```

But your code has

```
  EditText timeView = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.time_view);
```

Change above line to.

```
   EditText timeView = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.timeView);
```